# Invert mouse movement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, mouse

I've been trying to write a script that inverts mouse movement. I have a "functioning" script:

```
import mouse
    
last_pos = mouse.get_position()


def on_move(event):
    global last_pos

    if isinstance(event, mouse._mouse_event.MoveEvent):
        new_pos = ((last_pos[0] - event.x) * 2, (last_pos[1] - event.y) * 2)
        print()
        print(f'{last_pos = }')
        print(f'{new_pos = }')
        mouse.move(*new_pos, absolute=False)
        last_pos = mouse.get_position()
        print(f'*{last_pos = }')


mouse.hook(on_move)
input('Press enter to stop...')
```

Although the issue is, when i remove the print statements, the script no longer does the job:

```
import mouse

last_pos = mouse.get_position()


def on_move(event):
    global last_pos

    if isinstance(event, mouse._mouse_event.MoveEvent):
        new_pos = ((last_pos[0] - event.x) * 2, (last_pos[1] - event.y) * 2)
        mouse.move(*new_pos, absolute=False)
        last_pos = mouse.get_position()


mouse.hook(on_move)
input('Press enter to stop...')
```

If you know a solution to my problem or a better way to do what i'm trying to do, please respond :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of an expert in Python, but I think the print statements slow down *just a bit* for it to work, because obviously when you remove the print statements it goes crazy. So I think you might need to keep the print statements for it to work.

I tested out the following code, which gets rid of the print statements:

```
import mouse
import asyncio

last_pos = mouse.get_position()


def on_move(event):
    global last_pos

    if isinstance(event, mouse._mouse_event.MoveEvent):
        new_pos = ((last_pos[0] - event.x) * 2, (last_pos[1] - event.y) * 2)
        asyncio.sleep(0)
        mouse.move(*new_pos, absolute=False)
        last_pos = mouse.get_position()

mouse.hook(on_move)
input('Press enter to stop...')
```

^^ I think this works just as well ( or better ) but I don't know if its recommended.

Comment: Asyncio sleep is a coroutine, does it still function?

Comment: It does give a warning, but it still functions

Comment: The mouse movement is really glitchy

Comment: Yea, that's all I got, in this case I think you should just stick to the print statements.